# Turning off auto settings in picamera to remove persistent white spot in photos

Tags: camera, picamera

I'm using the Arducam 5 Megapixel camera (meant for Raspberry Pi) because it has the capability for changing the lenses, and using the `picamera` module to run it (in Python 3). I'm taking pictures that need to have very consistent lighting, but all the pictures have a bright white spot in the corner, even when the camera is entirely covered, so this is clearly either a problem with the camera, or some sort of auto-contrast or auto-lighting adjust that `picamera` does. Is there some way to to turn this sort of thing off with the `picamera` module to see which it is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late for this answer to help you, but hopefully this'll help future readers.

I found a PiCamera docs page that has advice for the topic.

The short version is this:

- set the shutter_speed
- set the iso
- set exposure_mode to 'off'
- set awb_mode to off
- set awb_gains

Digital_gain and analog_gain can't be set; they stay at what the auto-exposure set them to. <s>Setting exposure_mode to off immediately seems to reliably keep both at zero (though this is a hacky solution at best)</s>. When you query the analogue_gain or the digital_gain it will always reply zero if you do it before the camera is warmed up (wait for a second after turning off the exposure_mode to see their true values).

There's a github gist to set them: https://gist.github.com/rwb27/a23808e9f4008b48de95692a38ddaa08/

I've tried out the gist and the gains must be greater than 1. Anything lower than that automatically gets set to 1.

The Picam 1.13 docs page (Basic Recipe 3.5 "Capturing consistent images") has a lot more detail and advice on how to manually set the values.